Error: Provider not set or invalid (safari + chrome problem)
I have deployed an ERC20 token on Sepolia. See it here: https://augustwarshauer.com/AugustCoin
It's hosted on github pages, so I cant use node or anything (if I can, news to me).
In my chrome browser, all works normally and the leaderboard function works. But in incognito, it fails and gives reason "Error: Provider not set or invalid". In safari, it fails and gives a different reason. You can see the code on the website, but I'll provide it down below too.
Code:
const profilesAddress = "0x439f3d1A16698aCD2BD74e01CBe992c9D0CCf1F5";
const coinAddress = "0x2e992BF3732E71A83E44251f9B0dE80553A73632";
const faucetAddress = "0x24AcE8d1f490E05C5A66d6186bAfe051CCb3eEdc";


let web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
let profiles_contract = new web3.eth.Contract(profilesABI, profilesAddress);
let coin_contract = new web3.eth.Contract(coinABI, coinAddress);
let faucet_contract = new web3.eth.Contract(faucetABI, faucetAddress);


async function createLeaderboard() {
  console.log('hi');
  const fullprofiles = await profiles_contract.methods.getAllProfiles().call();
  console.log(fullprofiles[0]);
  const walletIDs = [...fullprofiles[0]]; 
  const walletNames = [...fullprofiles[1]]; 
  const walletBalances = [];

  console.log(walletIDs);
  console.log(walletNames);

  for (let i=0; i< walletIDs.length; i++) {
    let addy = walletIDs[i];
    try {
      let singleaddy = await coin_contract.methods.balanceOf(addy).call();
      walletBalances.push(singleaddy.slice(0,singleaddy.length-18));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error fetching balance for ${addy}:`, error);
    }
    }
  
  const sortedwalletBalances = [];
  const sortedwalletIDs = [];
  const sortedwalletNames = [];




  while (walletBalances.length != 0) {
    let peakindex = 0;
    for (let i=0; i < walletBalances.length; i++) {
      if (Number(walletBalances[i]) > Number(walletBalances[peakindex])) {
        peakindex = i; 
      }
    }

    sortedwalletBalances.push(walletBalances[peakindex]);
    sortedwalletIDs.push(walletIDs[peakindex]);
    sortedwalletNames.push(walletNames[peakindex]);
    walletBalances.splice(peakindex, 1);
    walletIDs.splice(peakindex, 1);
    walletNames.splice(peakindex, 1);

  }
  const leaderboard = document.getElementById("leaderboard");

  for (let i=0; i< sortedwalletBalances.length; i++) {

    leaderboard.innerHTML += `<div class="roww">
    <div class="namee">${sortedwalletNames[i]}</div><div class="scoree">${sortedwalletBalances[i]}</div>
    </div>
    `;

  }

  
}
createLeaderboard();



You’re getting the error "Error: Provider not set or invalid" because in incognito/private mode, the injected provider i.e., the window.ethereum object is not available by default.
It’s mentioned in EIP-5593 under Restrictions for providers section as:

Provider objects MAY be accessible in private (incognito) windows.

In Brave Browser, it’s disabled, as mentioned in this issue.
I’m not sure about the Chrome though, but in this post on Reddit, someone has mentioned some links of the docs to enable extensions (not particularly related to MetaMask or any wallet extension though).

Extensions in Chrome Incognito mode.
Extensions in Mozilla Firefox Private mode.

Also, it’s not available in Safari browser, therefore the MetaMask extension is not available for the same, as mentioned here.

Thanks for the insight! I should mention though, I went to another computer to test it in normal chrome, and the leaderboard didn't work there either. Same with on my phone on chrome. Why would this be if it's not in incognito? You can check yourself: https://augustwarshauer.com/AugustCoin

Fixed. Problem was wallets defaulted to mainnet and mine is deployed on sepolia. So you have to change network with some more code, which prompts user to do so and fixes all problems
